Safari text too bold
I have a website made with React in which the user can change the font of the page as he wants and for that I have this code
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!!font) {
            const fontUrl = `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${encodeURIComponent(font)}:wght@400;700&ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap`;
            const style = document.createElement('style');
            style.innerText = `
                @import url('${fontUrl}');
                body {
                    font-family: '${font}', 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important;
                }
            `;
            document.head.appendChild(style);
            
            // Cleanup function to remove the style when the component is unmounted or if the font prop changes
            return () => {
                document.head.removeChild(style);
            };
        }
    }, [font]);

and everything works fine except in Safari where the text is very bold
the properties:
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

do not fix my problem
this is what it looks like in chrome
chrome
and this is what it looks like in safari
safari

Can you add a screenshot of the issue in Safari?

Your CSS query can't work the correct tuple syntax would be https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${encodeURIComponent(font)}:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700. See also: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2

You should always check the validity of a dynamic CSS query by opening it in your browser. Unfortunately the google fonts API is unforgiving and won't return any CSS if there are even minor errors.

In CSS code, it can be useful to specify the font weight value by default. Have you tried it?
useEffect(() => {
    if (!!font) {
        const fontUrl = `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${encodeURIComponent(font)}:wght@400;700&ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap`;
        const style = document.createElement('style');
        style.innerText = `
        @import url('${fontUrl}');
          body {
           font-family: '${font}', 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important;
        font-weight: 400;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
      }
        `;
        document.head.appendChild(style);
        
        // Cleanup function to remove the style when the component is unmounted or if the font prop changes
        return () => {
            document.head.removeChild(style);
        };
    }
}, [font]);


yes, I've changed the font-weigth where I need it, but it doesn't solve my problem either.
